# Hat disappears when reloading an edited post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, winter-bash-2012

A couple of times, I've noticed users who'd been wearing hats suddenly *not* wearing hats any longer. This appears to have been the result of reloading their posts via the *"This post has been edited*" notification.

Refreshing the page entirely restores the hat.  Seems like a bug, but I'm not finding any previous meta questions about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JavaScript to insert hats onto the page is only ever run once - when the page finishes loading. Any time a Gravatar gets added (or in this case, replaced) on the page, it will *not* get a hat. This is just another place where adding code for hats is simply not worthwhile.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.